# Clojure agent's send function is blocking

Tags: clojure

```
(def queue-agent (agent (clojure.lang.PersistentQueue/EMPTY)))
(send queue-agent conj "some data for the queue")
(println "test output")
```

If I run this code, after a couple (!) of seconds the console will output `test output` and then nothing happens (program is not terminating). I've just checked against a couple of sources that all said the `send` function is asynchronous and should return immediately to the calling thread. So what's wrong with this? Why is it not returning? Is there something wrong with me? Or with my environment?

Comment: I'm running Clojure version `1.5.1` btw if that helps.

Comment: Are you using the default `send` executor? (Have you called `set-agent-send-executor!` to specify your own executor that perhaps has a bounded queue?)

Comment: Yes I'm just using the default `send` executor, haven't changed anything here.

Comment: Just to make sure this can't be it, I've tried using Clojure version 1.6.0 and interchanging the agent's content for an empty vector `[]`. Nothing changed.

Comment: I'd suggest producing a thread dump to see where it is blocking. (`kill -3` or debug in an IDE.)

Comment: Nothing is blocking.`-main` is done, but you have a threadpool that you have used, and you haven't told the vm it is OK to shut the threads down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have two issues: long startup time, and the program does not exit.

Startup: Clojure does not do any tree shaking. When you run a Clojure program, you load and bootstrap the compiler, and initialize namespaces, on every run. A couple of seconds sounds about right for a bare bones Clojure program.

Hanging: If you use the agent thread pool, you must run `shutdown-agents` if you want the program to exit. The vm simply doesn't know it is safe to shut them down.

Comment: You are right about the startup time. I had the feeling that the time until the output was longer than the usual startup time. But it's not. I verified this by adding an output in the beginning: There is no delay between the outputs.